# Converting ISO time to std::chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have the following function to convert a ISO type string to a `std::chrono::time_point` format with milliseconds precision. The code always worked fine on Linux, but now I need to convert it to Windows.

To use the same code I compiled it with `_WIN32`flag for Windows and changed the `strptime` code that is not supported on VS2010, the compiler I´m using.

On windows it does not convert properly - for for evey single time string I enter the remaining result is incorrect. I cannot find out what am I doing wrong:

```
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> convertISOStringToTimePoint(std::string isoString)
        {
            struct tm timeDate;

#ifdef _WIN32
            timeDate.tm_year = std::stoi(isoString.substr(0, 4));
            timeDate.tm_mon = std::stoi(isoString.substr(5, 2)) - 1;
            timeDate.tm_mday = std::stoi(isoString.substr(8, 2));
            timeDate.tm_hour = std::stoi(isoString.substr(11, 2));
            timeDate.tm_min = std::stoi(isoString.substr(14, 2));
            timeDate.tm_sec = std::stoi(isoString.substr(17, 2));
            timeDate.tm_isdst = -1;
#else
            strptime(isoString.c_str(), "%FT%TZ", &timeDate);
#endif
            time_t t = mktime(&timeDate);

            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time;
            time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t);

            auto timeMs = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time);

            int value = std::stoi(isoString.substr(20,3));

            timeMs += std::chrono::milliseconds(value);

            return timeMs;
        }
```

Help appreciated to find out what´s going on here....

Comment: What compiler are you using on windows?

Comment: You're being vague. Please present your [MCVE].

Comment: On windows VS2010.

Comment: That could be your problem.  I would try a new more standard complaint version like MSVS 2015.  You can use the free community edition.

Comment: After upgrading to MSVS 2015, try this: http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html#Parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve found the problem and post the solution:

`struct tm` is based on years since 1900, so the line:

`timeDate.tm_year = std::stoi(isoString.substr(0, 4));`

should be:

`timeDate.tm_year = std::stoi(isoString.substr(0, 4)) - 1900;`

Also, the `struct tm` should be cleaned before used:

```
struct tm timeDate
memset(&timeDate, 0, sizeof(timeDate));
```

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since `mktime` uses your current local timezone, my psychic debugging skills tell me that the ISO timestamp you're given is probably in UTC rather than localtime.